# How to Create Friends Object having 2 foreign keys?

Tags: django, django-views, python-3.6

I have a friends database which has following fields:

```
class Friends:
          status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
          from_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'from_user')
          to_user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="friend_user")
          date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
          date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

          def create(self,request, **kwargs, ):
              friend = self.create(from_user=request.user.id, status="Pending")
          return friend


          class Meta:
              unique_together = (('from_user', 'to_user'),)

          def __str__(self):
              return self.to_user
```

I am unable to create friend object in the view as given below:

```
def add_friend(request, pk): 
         """Sending friend request to email"""
          f = Friend(from_user=request.user.id,to_user=to_user.id,status= "Pending")
        f.save()
```

Attribute error: Manager isn't accessible via User instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# You need to store in id instead of object

def add_friend(request, pk): 
    """Sending friend request to email"""
    f = Friend(from_user_id=request.user.id,to_user_id=to_user.id,status= "Pending")
    f.save()
```

Comment: Unable to redirect to a page. It gives Value error Cannot assign "2 " Friend.from_user must be User instance.